# Windows 7 indicates "you need permission to perform this action" (deleting file)

Tags: windows-7, security, permissions

I'm logged in as an Administrator on Windows 7.  When I try to delete a folder (which shows Security settings indicating that Administrators have FULL access) I get a message that :

You require permission from SYSTEM to make changes to this file.

I don't have any other user accounts on this computer.

What's up with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out:

The file is owned by SYSTEM  (system service)

You have to change the ownership via command line: takeown /f   (this is from [How To Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/how-to-delete-a-system-file-in-windows-vista/) which then recommends using the CACLS command but that's been deprecated and it's easier to do it via the Security interface)

Right click the file and choose Properties> Security tab> choose Administrators (if you are one) then set the Edit Permissions, setting it to FULL.

Comment: I was going to suggest that, but then I decided not because you said you had permissions.
Well, I guess if that work, good, thanks for passing that on, I will have to remember that.

Comment: When I try this, I get "Access is denied". So I'm not even able to modify the permissions.

Answer (score 1):

It was my company's anti-virus software not allowing the download. It would download the file, then say:

> You require permissions from DOMAIN\USER to make changes to this file

Even though I am a domain admin. I disabled my anti-virus (in this case VIPRE) and it worked. Downloaded the file just fine. VIPRE thought FileZilla was a "known bad" in its application rating, and it was blocking the download.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was trying to delete a folder from a network share which was write-protected.

Because the PCs had similar names I didn't realize that I was working on the remote folder instead of the local folder.

Solution: simply delete the correct (local) folder.